# Quoted Title Possessive

Tags: punctuation

I am editing a story where the game show "Jeopardy!" is used as a possessive within a quote. Should I insert the 's within the single quotes around the name, such as 'Jeopardy!'s', or would the 's go outside the single quotes, such as 'Jeopardy!''s? I cannot use italics, because house style calls for quotes around the title (journalistic style).

Also, would it be:

"Jeopardy!'s" success was due to host Alex Trebeck.

"Jeopardy!"'s success was due to host Alex Trebeck.

Thanks.

Comment: Simpler: use *the show's...*

Comment: Or "the success of *Jeopardy!*" if you have the freedom to make minor changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd generally go for:

> *Jeopardy*'s

Which is to say, italicise the series name (as is generally normal), drop trailing punctuation (the exclamation mark) and add the *'s*.

This can be seen followed by others such as [here](http://www.slate.com/articles/arts/culturebox/2011/03/more_jeopardy_trivia.html). An example which doesn't italicise because it isn't in a headline is [here](http://mic.com/articles/81019/jeopardy-s-new-champion-uses-a-controversial-game-theory-strategy-to-win-big)* and one that just uses a style of not italicising at all is [here](http://www.business2community.com/social-buzz/jeopardys-women-want-category-proves-incredibly-sexist-01022968).

That's the general answer to a general question. You have a specific constraint though because:

> I cannot use italics, because house style calls for quotes around the title

If you can't do something because of the house style, then do what the house style says to do.

If the house style doesn't cover the case in question, then do what the person who is in charge of the house style does.

This goes for anything where a house style causes difficulties. When a house style has a rule about something, then it's not your problem any more; find out whose problem it is, and have them deal with it.

---

*I never understood what was so "controversial" about someone playing the game properly for once.